# Modifying List Item permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a Sharepoint list that I'm using as a form.  Everyone in the company needs to view/modify the form to submit information, but I would like to keep the response from the form viewable to just a few people. Is there a way to do that, without clicking each item and managing permissions for that item?  Can that be done with a workflow?

Comment: You want to give access to these specific people to whole list or just selective records?

Comment: I want to set permissions so that everyone can access the list to submit information, and then set permissions for a few specific people to view the display page.

Comment: Refer the first option provided by @teylyn in the below answer

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

- Set up the list so users can only see and edit their own responses. (List settings > Advanced settings > set Read Access and Create and Edit access to "Items that were created by the user".
- Create a SharePoint group for people who should see all items, e.g. ListManagers
- Set up list permissions so that Visitors (everyone in the company) have Contribute access and the ListManagers group gets full access for the list.

Another option:

- Leave the Advanced settings at the default, so that everyone can see all items.
- Change the default view of the list to show only items created by the current user.
- Create a page that shows an XLV with the default view and serve that to everybody.
- Create another page that shows an XLV with all items and give permissions for that page only to the limited group of people.

The second method is more for convenience than for security and will not prevent savvy users from accessing the data they cannot see in the default view.